# How to bypass the Easy Digital Downloads checkout process?

Tags: plugins, third-party-applications

I've decided to use [Easy Digital Downloads](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/) as a base to create a secure download area for a client. The client will be uploading general files such as .pdf's and word documents for their members.

What I'd like to do is bypass the checkout process of Easy Digital Downloads so users can download a file straight away, without having to first add a download to their cart, checking out, and then receiving the email with the download link.

Is anyone familiar with EDD and how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of Easy Digital Downloads. It's definitely possible, though if you're just looking for download tracking with out any ecommerce transactions, I'd suggest you use the [Download Monitor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/) plugin from Mike Jolley.

Comment: Yeah I gave download monitor a go not too long ago after searching for an alternative but found it was littered with PHP notices and could hardly use it. I also found it not to be very extensible for my needs. Might have to give it another go though. I find EDD to be a great base for what I'm trying to achieve and very flexible, just stuck on that one thing.